# PHP Session issue for AddOn domain

Tags: session

I have installed cPanel (EasyApache) for a domain (Domain1.com)
Later i have added a new add on domain (Domain2.com), but when i am starting php session for domain2.com it is setting domain1.con cookie in chrome network response.

set-cookie: PHPSESSID=51gjk7jr3qnscrb250j97mibh6; expires=Sat, 09-Oct-2021 15:00:35 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.domain1.com

Also chrome is giving warning for this "This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regard to the current host url".

**Directory structure**

```
public_html/ (for domain1.com)
public_html/mysubdomain/domain2/ (for domain2.com)
```

**PHP Version used**

```
php5.6 for domain1.com
php7.1 for domain2.com
```

Is their any setting in php.ini or any other for fix this ?

Comment: cPanel and other hosting panels are off-topic for ServerFault, please see https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Yes that is off-topic, i don't know but this problem can be due to php.ini settings. which is on-topic cPanel

Comment: Questions involving cPanel, even of this nature, remain off-topic because cPanel affects everything on the server, including how things like `php.ini` are configured. (I also don't think this has anything to do with php.ini; and it's *additionally* off-topic for dealing with an unsupported version of PHP.)

Answer (score 0):

Got that solution, edited php.ini for domain2.com

by setting this everything is working as expected

```
session.cookie_domain=".domain2.com"
```